# Change nested setTimeout functions to efficient loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of students - each student being a DIV with a specific class and an ID.

I also have an array of student IDs, which I have randomised.

What I'd like to do is the following:

1. Pick a random student
2. Highlight the relevant DIV in purple (the `pulse` class)
3. Brief pause (like 0.2s)
4. Pick another random student
5. Rinse and repeat 1-3 10 times in total
6. Highlight the selected student in a different colour (`selected` class)

The code below works correctly...

```
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#" + arr[1]).addClass('pulse');
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $("#" + arr[1]).removeClass('pulse');

                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $("#" + arr[2]).addClass('pulse');
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                $("#" + arr[2]).removeClass('pulse');

                                    setTimeout(function() {
                                        $("#" + arr[3]).addClass('pulse');
                                        setTimeout(function() {
                                            $("#" + arr[3]).removeClass('pulse');

                                            setTimeout(function() {
                                                $("#" + arr[4]).addClass('pulse');
                                                setTimeout(function() {
                                                    $("#" + arr[4]).removeClass('pulse');

                                                    setTimeout(function() {
                                                        $("#" + arr[5]).addClass('pulse');
                                                        setTimeout(function() {
                                                            $("#" + arr[5]).removeClass('pulse');

                                                            setTimeout(function() {
                                                                $("#" + arr[6]).addClass('pulse');
                                                                setTimeout(function() {
                                                                    $("#" + arr[6]).removeClass('pulse');

                                                                    setTimeout(function() {
                                                                        $("#" + arr[7]).addClass('pulse');
                                                                        setTimeout(function() {
                                                                            $("#" + arr[7]).removeClass('pulse');

                                                                            setTimeout(function() {
                                                                                $("#" + arr[8]).addClass('pulse');
                                                                                setTimeout(function() {
                                                                                    $("#" + arr[8]).removeClass('pulse');

                                                                                    setTimeout(function() {
                                                                                        $("#" + arr[9]).addClass('pulse');
                                                                                        setTimeout(function() {
                                                                                            $("#" + arr[9]).removeClass('pulse');

                                                                                            setTimeout(function() {
                                                                                                $("#" + arr[10]).addClass('pulse');
                                                                                                setTimeout(function() {
                                                                                                    $("#" + arr[10]).removeClass('pulse');
                                                                                                    $("#" + arr[0]).addClass('activeClass');
                                                                                                    Dojo.disableButtons(false);
                                                                                                }, 250);
                                                                                            }, 250);

                                                                                        }, 250);
                                                                                    }, 250);

                                                                                }, 250);
                                                                            }, 250);

                                                                        }, 250);
                                                                    }, 250);

                                                                }, 250);
                                                            }, 250);

                                                        }, 250);
                                                    }, 250);

                                                }, 250);
                                            }, 250);

                                        }, 250);
                                    }, 250);

                            }, 250);
                        }, 250);

                    }, 250);
                }, 250);
```

But is incredibly ugly.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this using a for loop?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is using jQuery an option?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter he's *already* using jQuery!

Comment: Yes please, we need to use jQuery.

Comment: @JamesBall can you then try using something like `.toggleClass()` and `.delay()` to make transitions more concise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) function is what you need.
This executes an other function until you call `clearInterval`.
[EDIT]
Here is an idea:

```
var arr = YOUR ARRAY HERE;
var index = 0;
var t = setInterval(function(){
    if (index > 0){
       $('#' + arr[index - 1]).removeClass('pulse'); //remove class from previous
    }
    if (index < 10){
       $('#' + arr[index]).addClass('pulse'); //add class to current element
    }
    else { 
      clearInterval(t);//stop everything
    }
    index ++;
}, 250)
```

This might not work. It's of the top of my head, but it should give you and idea.

Comment: Hi @Marius I think that this is along the right lines. Do you have any working examples.

Comment: Thanks @Marius. Works perfectly. Just 1 typo on the 4th last line. `clearInderval`.

Comment: @JamesBall. Ha!..glad to hear it. I fixed the typo.

Comment: @JamesBall Note that if the inner code takes too long, this solution will break your page. (see my edit on my answer for more information)

Answer (score 5):

You could use a function (and obviously rename it something more meaningful):

```
function lessMessy(index) {
    $("#" + arr[index]).addClass('pulse');
    if (index === 10) {
        $("#" + arr[0]).addClass('activeClass');
        Dojo.disableButtons(false);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#" + arr[index]).removeClass('pulse');
            lessMessy(index + 1)
        }, 250)
    }
}

lessMessy(1)
```

**EDIT**: Note that this is better than `setInterval` because it will *always* wait a quarter of a second. If the code inside takes longer than 1/4 of a second, then `setInterval` will just skip that iteration. This will lead to a broken page, since the `pulse` class will not be removed from the previous element.

Comment: This is close but it never adds the class to any elements.

Comment: Adding this line to the end of your code block would make it equivalent: `setTimeout(function() {lessMessy(1);}, 250);`

Comment: @devnull69 I was assuming that was obvious, but okay

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more verbose / general approach with callbacks:

```
var pulseStudent = function( student, callback ){
  student = $('#' + student);
  student.addClass('pulse');
  setTimeout(function(){student.removeClass('pulse');}, 250);
  setTimeout(callback, 500);
};

var pulseStudents = function( students, callback ){
  var student = students.pop();
  if ( student ) {
    pulseStudent( student, function(){
      pulseStudents( students, callback );
    });
  }
  else {
    callback();
  }
};

pulseStudents( arr.slice(0), function(){
  $("#" + arr[0]).addClass('activeClass');
  Dojo.disableButtons(false);
});
```